# Why is $2\sqrt5$ equal to $\sqrt{20}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What does the 2 in front mean? Is it like root 5 * root 5? It can't be because the answer doesn't numerically evaluate to 2root5. Just looking for some intuition here because I am reading the numbers wrong. It's not $5^2$ either or $2^5$. I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{20}=\sqrt{4\times  5}=\underbrace{\sqrt{4}}_{=2}\times  \sqrt 5=2\times \sqrt 5=2\sqrt 5$$

We usually write $ab$ for $a\times b$. And here, $2\times \sqrt{5}=2\sqrt 5$

Answer (score 2):

$2\sqrt{5}$ means $2\cdot\sqrt{5}$, i.e. $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}$.

Then $2\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{20}$ are both positive numbers whose squares equal $20$, hence they're equal.

Answer (score 2):

$2\sqrt{5}=2\times \sqrt{5} = \sqrt{2 \times2\times5}= \sqrt{4\times5}=\sqrt{20}$.

It is just like polynomial $xy$ is $x\times y$  or $ab$ is $a\times b$. Generally when there is no sign in between irrational and natural number it is considered as multiplication(just like polynomial.)